# Toll-Number match in string without using regex in Python

Tags: python, string, split

sentence = "The toll-no is 800-123-2345 and 900-234-2345"

output = "800-123-2345"

I want to extract toll number which starts with the number 800.

```
sentence = "800-123-1243 and 900-345-6578 and 911-798-5768 and 900-1234-1234"

output = "".join([char for char in sentence if char.isdigit()])
print(output)
```

```
# output-
80012312439003456578911798576890012341234
```

Comment: Is there only one such number in the sentence?

Answer (score 3):

A non-regex way could use a simple list comprehension with string operations:

```
sentence = "800-123-1243 and 900-345-6578 and 911-798-5768 and 900-1234-1234"

out = [word for word in sentence.split()
       if word.startswith('800') and word.replace('-', '').isdigit()]
```

Output: `['800-123-1243']`

If you only want the first match (if any):

```
out = next((word for word in sentence.split()
            if word.startswith('800') and word.replace('-', '').isdigit()),
           None)
```

Output: `'800-123-1243'`

*NB. the `word.replace('-', '').isdigit()` is not strictly required with the provided example, but can help if the sentence is more complex and there is a risk of having words starting in `800` that are not phone numbers.*

Comment: Nice. But this part - ```.. and word.replace..``` seems to be `no` effect?

Comment: Meaning it can yield some *out* as - ```[w for w in sentence.split() if w.startswith('800') ]```

Comment: @Daniel this avoids issues in case you have something like `sentence = "800abc 800-123-1243"` by ensuring you only select Toll-Number like substrings (i.e. only digits once the `-` were removed). This was hinted in OP's original answer because of the `char.isdigit()`. It can of course be left-out if such a case is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern of the number is 800-NNN-NNNN, then you can find the first match using a simple regex:

```
import re

match = re.search(r'800-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}', sentence)
result = match.group() if match else None
```